# How can I obtain Blade Shards?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I am interested in obtaining an Ascended **Tempered Spinal Blades** back piece. In order to create one, I need a total of 925 Blade Shards. However, I appear to be gaining Blade Shards very slowly and I would like to complete this back piece very soon.

Is there a good method of farming Blade Shards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing by "very slowly" you mean from gathering sprockets in your home instance?

These items were dropped in abundance during the [Escape from Lion's Arch](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Escape_from_Lion%27s_Arch) part of the Living Story; since you can't go back in time to that, you can currently only get them in limited quantities from [Aetherblades](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Aetherblades), e.g. in the Edge of the Mists, in the Aetherblade path of Twilight Arbor, or wherever else you can find them - I think some are still around the [Not so secret](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Not_So_Secret) jumping puzzle and you can get them from the chest at the end of that JP as well.

But yes, the going will be slow compared to farming them while the Living Story was going on.

Edit: As Gwen said in the comment, you can also use the [Blade Shard recipe](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Blade_Shard) to multiply blade shards using sprockets and some dust. Assuming you have enough sprockets, that should speed things up a bit.

Comment: You can turn [Sprockets into Blade Shards](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Blade_Shard) with the mystic forge

Comment: @Gwen: Indeed - updated the answer, thanks for pointing that out :-)

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter The sprocket node in your home instance occasionally drops these as well

Comment: @Andreas: Yes, hence my first sentence: "... from gathering sprockets in your home instance". :-)

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter Can't believe I somehow skipped that first sentence XS